# How to solve $2^n > 2n^3$ for n?

Tags: inequality, logarithms, computational-complexity

I'm studying algorithm complexity and big O notation. I have these two functions that express time complexity: $f(n) = 2^n$ and $g(n) = 2n^3$.

The question is, when is g(n) dominated by f(n)? To solve it, I know I need to find a value for n where $f(n) > g(n)$. I tried multiple ways, using log properties, but I didn't get anywhere.

This is how far I got:
$$2^n > 2n^3$$
$$2^{n-1} > n^3$$
$$\log_n2^{n-1} > 3$$
$$(n-1)\log_n2 > 3$$
$$\log_n2 > 3\cdot\frac{1}{(n-1)}$$
$$2 > n^{\frac{3}{(n-1)}}$$

If I go any far, I end up going in circles. I'll appreciate any explanations or hints on this problem.
I'll appreciate any explanations or hints on this problem.

Comment: If you plug it into Wolfram Alpha you'll get an exact expression involving the Lambert W function -- but if this is an exercise in a complexity context, you're almost certainly just supposed to solve it for _integer_ $n$ by trial and error.

Comment: You might also find it informative to graph $2^n - 2n^3$. What you should find is that the function will cross the $x$-axis at some point, then lie above the $x$-axis forever after. You can read the integer $n$ that solves your problem off the graph. This can be your "guess" for the correct value of $n$. From here, you can use induction to show that the inequality holds for all larger $n$, and even show that the inequality doesn't hold for $n - 1$.

Comment: You could have gotten that last inequality from the second just by raising both sides to the power $\frac1{n-1}.$

Comment: What is $n$? I mean is $n$ an integer? If not, are you familiar on Lambert-W function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n$ is an integer, we can use a guess-and-check approach.  Since we know $2^{10} = 1024$ and $10^3 = 1000$, clearly $n > 10$.  Then calculating each side for $n \in \{11, 12, \ldots\}$ we see that the first instance where the inequality is satisfied is when $n = 12$.

Alternatively, Newton's method applied to $\log \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$ will work:  we have $$n_{k+1} = \frac{n_k (3 \log n_k + \log 2 - 3)}{n_k \log 2 - 3},$$ and with a suitable initial guess, say $n_0 = 10$, we get the sequence of iterates $$n_1 \approx 11.7027, \\ n_2 \approx 11.6132, \\ n_3 \approx 11.6130, \\ n_4 \approx 11.6130.$$

Comment: Are you sure? How about $n≤0$?

Comment: @lonestudent In the context of the question, which is about algorithmic complexity and big-$O$ notation, $n \le 0$ is not relevant.

Comment: I just concentrated on the question title.

Comment: If $n\leqslant0$, then  $2^n>0\geqslant2n^3$, hence $$2^n>2n^3\quad\text{for all }n\leqslant0\;.$$

Answer (score 1):

For any $n\geq 1,$ $$\frac{(n+1)^3}{n^3}=1+\frac3n+\frac3{n^2}+\frac1{n^3}\leq 1+\frac7n.$$

So this value is $\leq 2$ when $n\geq 7.$ (*)

So if  we have an $n\geq 7$ such that $2^n> 2n^3,$ then it is true for $n+1,n+2,$ etc.

But $$2^{13}=2\cdot (2^4)^3>2\cdot 13^3$$

($n=12$ also work, but requires a little more computation. $n=11$ does not work, so neither does any $n<11.$)

---

You actually get $$\frac{(n+1)^3}{n^3}<2$$ for any $n\geq 7,$ but it doesnt change the answer.